# Pegar dia da semana em um select

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, servidor

Preciso saber como faço para dentro de um select (com `LEFT JOIN`, `INNER JOIN`) pegar o dia da semana de um campo de uma tabela, comparar e ver qual o dia da semana, se for 1 somar 2, se for 7 somar 1?

Exemplo:

```
case when datepart (weekday, campo.da.tabela) = 1 then campo.tabela+2 when (datepart (weekday, campo.da.tabela) = 7 then campo.tabela+ 1
```

mas dessa forma nao esta dando certo, não sei como montar.

Em SQL SERVER.

Comment: Olá @Rafael. A sua questão está pouco clara. Pode detalhar mais? O campo `campo.tabela` é inteiro? A semana começa no Domingo ou na Segunda?

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

Answer (score 1):

Sem conhecer bem o objetivo e a estrutura da tabela, considerando que a coluna `campo.tabela` é um inteiro e o início da semana começa ao **Domingo**, pode fazer a consulta da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT  campo.tabela = campo.tabela + (CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, campo.da.tabela)
        WHEN 1 THEN 2
        WHEN 7 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END)
FROM    Tabela
```

Caso pretenda alterar o início da semana para **Segunda-feira**, basta incluir este comando no início da sua consulta:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
```

Isto terá, como é óbvio, impacto nos seus resultados, nomeadamente, no número atribuído ao dia da semana da data em causa.